# How to edit magento RWD theme

Tags: theme, magento-1.9

I would like to customize my magento home page.

1. How to Edit fonts in magento rwd theme to default theme font?
2. How to edit color of the text in homepage?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may edit the skin\frontend\rwd\default\css\style.css. You will find the button class with font-family and color

```
.button, .cart-table .product-cart-actions .button, #co-shipping-method-form .buttons-set .button, .footer .button {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3399cc;
border: 0 none;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-family: -moz-fixed,"Helvetica Neue",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 19px;
padding: 7px 15px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

Line:911

Comment: As soon as the SASS is compiled all the changes would be lost. Should at least edit the _var.scss like osrecio suggested.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the default rwd files, but should instead properly customize it using theme fallback architecture documented in the other answer to this question. Also, you should make these changes to the scss file and recompile.

Answer (score 6):

You need modify the file _var.scss inside */skin/frontend/rwd/scss*

But to understand how works the theme you need read this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide